# Using Unicode character assertion 0x22a6

Tags: xetex, unicode

I am trying to typeset a document using Xelatex. The document contains assertion unicode character 0x22a6 but unable to render it.

I have tried several methods such as using newunicodechar package, fontspec, etc. but could'nt render the character successfully.

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: I have tried several fonts but couldn't get it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be available in any math font (and some text fonts) for example it is in latin modern math:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\begin{document}
```

You can (perhaps) use the math font as text font for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmainfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}

[text ^^^^22a6]


$ a \assert b $

\end{document}
```

The same markup would work for any font tha has the character.

```
$ a \assert b $

\end{document}
```

If you don't need it to be in Unicode position the actual character is available in any tex math font set (as `\vdash`)

Comment: I actually would like to render it as a text character instead of math symbol.

Comment: @Shahzad if the character is in your text font then `^^^^22a6` will work, if not then anything else is going to be equivalent to `$\assert$` or `$\vdash$` to obtain the character from a font that does have it.

Comment: @Shahzad updated answer

Answer (score 3):

If your font has no U+22A6 glyph, you can add a font face having it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Old Standard} % it has no U+22A6
\newfontface{\assertionfont}{FreeSerif} % it has U+22A6

\newunicodechar{⊦}{\mbox{\assertionfont ⊦}}

\begin{document}

This is \texttt{U+22A6}: ⊦

\end{document}
```

[image]

Among the fonts in TeX Live having the glyph you find Asana Math, Latin Modern Math, Libertinus Serif and Sans, Linux Libertine, Linux Biolinum, STIX and STIX Math, TeX Gyre {Bonum|Pagella|Schola|Termes} Math, XITS and XITS Math.

Note that you *can* use, say, Asana Math in a `\newfontface` declaration.